# The higher moments of truncated Gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We assume that 
$$X \sim N(0,1/d),$$ where $d\rightarrow \infty$. For $\delta > 0$ sufficiently small. My question is, what is the correct order (in terms of $d$) of 
$$
E(X^k~|~X>1/\sqrt{d^{1-\delta}}).
$$

Comment: do you know how to calculate the characteristic function of the truncated gaussian ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I can calculate the characteristic function. However, it is too complicated to get the moment from the characteristic function since it doesn't have a closed form solution.

Comment: Are you sure you got the truncation correctly? $X$ is getting more and more concentrated around $0$ while truncation point drifts off to $\infty$. Did you mean to truncate at $d^{-\frac 1 2(1-\delta)}$?

Comment: In that interpretation, the core calculation is of $E(N^k|N>L)\sim L^k$ for standard normal $N$. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution for MGF of a truncated normal.

Comment: @A.S. You are right, I meant $d^{-(1-\delta)/2}$. Sorry for the typo. So how do you get the order of moments from the MGF, since it involves the Gaussian CDF $\Phi$ there?

Comment: That was just a general reference - I didn't use it in the first order approximation. Density of a normal $\phi(L)$ falls off really fast for large $L$, so the first order contribution is $L^k$. For further orders, you'll need to use $P(N>L)\sim \phi(L)/L$ (and there are more expansions to higher order) and $E(N|N>L)= L+O(1/L)$ that follows from it (I think the constant in O is 1 in fact).

Comment: From that page you can also see that $E(N^2|N>L)=L^2+1+O(1/L)$, so it looks like $E(N^k|N>L)=L^K+O(L^{K-2})$ where the constant in O is again probably 1.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks a lot! I think this is the answer. Would you turn into an answer with more details? So people who encounter the same problem can have a reference.